# How can I adjust z-index of a scaled image that is covered with footer

Tags: html, css, z-index

so I have this problem, I want to scale an image while hovering with mouse on it. But the image is very close to the footer. While hovering, the image is covered with the footer. Can you help me?

CSS:

```
body {
background-color: mintcream;
transition: color, background-color .5s;
}
.Me{
  width: 50%;
  height:auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: transform .5s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.Me:hover{
  transform: scale(1.5);

}

.body2{
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
  padding:10px 30px 10px 30px;
  height: max-content;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: background-color .5s;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  z-index: 0;
    }
footer{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.92);
  color: white;
  z-index:-1;

}
```

HTML-part of it

```
<div class="body2" id="body2">
<h1>Vitajte na mojej stránke!</h1>
  <br>
   <p>jafjskfkajsbfjkabfjkabsfjkabsfjkbasfjkbasjfkbsajkfbajksfbjkasfb
jkasbfjksabfjasbfjkbasfjkbsajfkbsajkfjfbsajfbaskjfbjskafbjkasbfjksabfjkasbfjksabfjkasbfjbasjfkbaskjfbaskjfbasjkfb</p>
<br>
  <img class= Me src="img/Me.jpg" alt="Me" height="2320" width="3088"/>
</div>


</body>

<footer>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</footer>
```

Printscreen (Dont mind the photo content):
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c58Ds.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiLXF.png)

Comment: Pls add more context to your screenshots. "Before" and "after" could mean a lot of different things. Instead, describe how you got your output to look like in each image and whether they're symptoms or expected solution etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.body2` has overflow hidden, so it does not  let the image get out of its borders,

you don't have to use `z-index` just remove `overflow: hidden`

```css
body {
background-color: mintcream;
transition: color, background-color .5s;
}
.Me{
  width: 50%;
  height:auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: transform .5s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.Me:hover{
  transform: scale(1.5)
}

.body2{
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
  padding:10px 30px 10px 30px;
  height: max-content;
  /* overflow: hidden; remove*/
  transition: background-color .5s;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  z-index: 0;
    }
footer{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.92);
  color: white;
  z-index:-1;

}
```

```html
<div class="body2" id="body2">
<h1>Vitajte na mojej stránke!</h1>
  <br>
   <p>jafjskfkajsbfjkabfjkabsfjkabsfjkbasfjkbasjfkbsajkfbajksfbjkasfb
jkasbfjksabfjasbfjkbasfjkbsajfkbsajkfjfbsajfbaskjfbjskafbjkasbfjksabfjkasbfjksabfjkasbfjbasjfkbaskjfbaskjfbasjkfb</p>
<br>
  <img class= Me src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5195763/pexels-photo-5195763.jpeg?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&dl=pexels-allec-gomes-5195763.jpg&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=8750&w=7000" alt="Me" height="2320" width="3088"/>


</div>

<footer>
 <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am just learning, so really thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to fix it with `z-index` so I used `display:none` on the footer when the user hovers the image.

```css
body {
  background-color: mintcream;
  transition: color, background-color .5s;
}

.Me {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: transform .5s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.Me:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
.Me:hover ~ footer {
  display:none;
}

.body2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin: 0 10% 0 10%;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  height: max-content;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: background-color .5s;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  z-index: 0;
}

footer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.92);
  color: white;
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="body2" id="body2">
  <h1>Vitajte na mojej stránke!</h1>
  <br>
  <p>jafjskfkajsbfjkabfjkabsfjkabsfjkbasfjkbasjfkbsajkfbajksfbjkasfb jkasbfjksabfjasbfjkbasfjkbsajfkbsajkfjfbsajfbaskjfbjskafbjkasbfjksabfjkasbfjksabfjkasbfjbasjfkbaskjfbaskjfbasjkfb
  </p>
  <br>
  <img class="Me" src="img/Me.jpg" alt="Me" height="2320" width="3088" />

  <footer>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```